# How do I block a path in traefik?

Tags: middleware, block, traefik, whitelist

How do I block a path in traefik?

For example, I created an IP whitelist middleware which works correctly and when applied blocks any domain I want using: **rule = Host(`domain.com`)
**
and also blocks a path such as:
**rule = "Host(`example.com`) || (Host(`example.org`) && Path(`/traefik`))"
**
But when I visit 'example.com//traefik' it bypasses the middleware and I can access the page. If I go to /traefik the IP whitelist middleware blocks the page as intended.

Note the // double fowardslash in the path, how do I block access to **//traefik** and **///traefik**, etc. The actual path I need to block is /xmlrpc.php, I'm seeing many requests going to //xmlrpc.php bypassing the whitelist middleware.

I was thinking about some type of regex that matches any string with /traefik inside of it, but I don't see any examples on the Traefik documentation.

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/

Sincerely,
-alexv305

I followed the documentation example:
https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/

Comment: The documentation is in the page you linked. Quote "Path(`/path`, `/articles/{cat:[a-z]+}/{id:[0-9]+}`, ...) Match exact request path. See "Regexp Syntax" below.
PathPrefix(`/products/`, `/articles/{cat:[a-z]+}/{id:[0-9]+}`) Match request prefix path. See "Regexp Syntax" below."